# Go: Remove hyphens from UUID

Tags: go

Thanks for all the help and support, I am getting from this forum as a beginner.
Now I am stuck with some other problem. I am generating uuid using  "uuid.New()" method from "https://github.com/google/uuid" lib. Is there any method to remove hyphens from UUID?

Thanks

Comment: Actually the library I am using does not provide randomUUID generation.

Comment: @Anvy The package referenced in the question does support random UUID generation. See [uuid.NewRandom](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#NewRandom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `github.com/google/uuid` package represents a UUID as an array of 16 bytes.  The array is the raw data of UUID, not the [hex encoded representation with hyphens](https://github.com/google/uuid/blob/bfb86fa49a73e4194d93bea18d7acfe3694438ce/uuid.go#L185).

No action is required to remove hyphens because the hyphens are not part of the data in the UUID value.

If you want to remove the hyphens from the [string representation returned by the String method](https://github.com/google/uuid/blob/bfb86fa49a73e4194d93bea18d7acfe3694438ce/uuid.go#L170), simply use `strings.Replace()` as follows:

```
uuid := uuid.New().String()
uuidWithoutHyphens := strings.Replace(uuid, "-", "", -1)
```